# Cannot remove bootstrap tabs css when not hovering?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to use Bootstrap tabs with my own CSS and it's mostly working well except for a small bug that I can't figure out. Whenever I click on a tab then stop hovering over it (but not click on anything else) it will display the original css tab background over that tab. I've tried changing the background / borders for every element but nothing seems to stop this from happening. [Screenshots of the problem can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J13qf.jpg) (My rep isn't high enough for embedded images yet!). Another note is that this problem doesn't occur in Safari.

Here's my Html and Css:

```
CSS:

.postTeamBytes {
    background-color: #EDF6F9;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #777;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav li {
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav li:hover{
    border: none;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav li:active{
    border: none;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav {
    border: none;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav:hover {
    border: none;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav:active {
    border: none;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav .active a {
    margin-top: -10px;

    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 50px;
    outline: 0;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav li a {
    margin-top: -5px;

    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 50px;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav .active {
    background-color: #EDF6F9;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.nav-tabs {
    background: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover{
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav a {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #333;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav a:hover {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav .active a {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #52ABC6;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav .active a:hover {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #52ABC6;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav .active a:active:hover {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #52ABC6;
}

.postTeamBytes .nav {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #A8D5E2;
 }

.postTeamBytes .nav-tabs {
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
}


HTML:

<div class="postTeamBytes">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#byteTab">BYTE</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#eventTab">EVENT</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#challengeTab">CHALLENGE</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The propierty you need to change is .nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus.

So... try

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus.
{
  background-color:transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  // whatever else you need to style
}
```

Go check my [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/BVUBCGffk8)